# GitHub command to force a checkin

Tags: git, github

I have code on my client that conflicts with a checked in version.  Is there a way to tell Git to "ignore the origin version and force my version over it"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using the `git push -f` command. The `-f` command is the "force" option, which pushes your current ref to the upstream, even if your current history is not derived from the upstream.

**You can easily lose work with this command.** Be careful.

Comment: More like, you **will** lose commits if you need to use -f.